# Broke my install while installing a theme

Tags: system, themes

I installed an Icon theme with elementary tweaks, I guess it was broken because the settings force closed, wingpanel disappeared and most of my apps won't start anymore... 
Right now I can only open firefox and the terminal...
Is there a way to either delete the broken icons folder, or change the icon theme through the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thing Terminal still works :) Open it and paste the line

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'elementary'
```

The default icon theme should now be restored.

Comment: If you go to settings -> about  there's a 'reset to defaults'button.

Comment: @user3801839 if his icon theme is broken, I believe the System Settings would be borked as well. But yes, that button restores everything to default, if you're able to get to it.

Comment: Thanks! Was very lucky with the terminal, this worked!

Comment: @EddoWagt You're welcome! Now please mark the question as answered, so that others that encounter this issue can find the answer quickly. Just curious, what was the broken icon theme you installed?

Comment: @VladPop I installed ePapirus. The problem is not the icon pack itself, but it got corrupted while extracting the package

Comment: Also, could you tell me how to mark this post as answered? Not sure how to do that

Comment: @EddoWagt To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. From here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @VladPop Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 0):

The reset to defaults is in the about menu in Administration.

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information, maybe the steps. Have a nice day!